# Google Translate widget - responsive

Tags: web, responsive-design, frontend, google-translate, web-frontend

On my Web page I put translate widget when i resize browsers widged does not change size

[image]

I  tried change css but i can change only css for Iframe

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function googleTranslateElementInit() {
            new google.translate.TranslateElement({
                pageLanguage: 'en',
                layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE
            }, 'google_translate_element');
        }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>

</head>
    <body>

        <div id="google_translate_element"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

do you heve any solution?

Comment: Please provide us the link to your website. It's hard to debug without code

Comment: I updated my Question @Rainfall

Comment: The answer provided does demonstrate to resize the frame pointed to in your question.  I you feel this adequately addresses your question, please select an answer that worked for you so that this question may be considered resolved.

Answer (score 9):

> **Google Translate popup Layout - responsive fixed**

```
<div id="google_translate_element" style="text-align: center;"></div>
 <style>
        .goog-te-banner-frame.skiptranslate {
            display: none !important;
        } 
        body {
            top: 0px !important; 
        }

        .goog-te-menu-frame {
        max-width:100% !important; 
        }
        .goog-te-menu2 { 
        max-width: 100% !important;
        overflow-x: scroll !important;
        box-sizing:border-box !important; 
        height:auto !important; 
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function googleTranslateElementInit() {
            new google.translate.TranslateElement({
                pageLanguage: 'en',
                autoDisplay: false,
                layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE
            }, 'google_translate_element');
            function changeGoogleStyles() {
                if($('.goog-te-menu-frame').contents().find('.goog-te-menu2').length) {
                    $('.goog-te-menu-frame').contents().find('.goog-te-menu2').css({
                        'max-width':'100%',
                        'overflow-x':'auto',
                        'box-sizing':'border-box',
                        'height':'auto'
                    });
                } else {
                    setTimeout(changeGoogleStyles, 50);
                }
            }
            changeGoogleStyles();
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Not the solution to resizing issue but maybe helpful. You can change the default layout in the init function of the google translate selector.
Change in the line
`layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE`
 to `layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.VERTICAL`
 or `layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.HORIZONTAL`.
These options will show the language choices in a vertical dropdown with also either the 'Made possible by Google Translate' label under or next to it.

Comment: This option has been the best solution for us as well. To style the select box similar to the OP's option, it can be style with css such as:

`.goog-te-gadget .goog-te-combo {`
margin: 0;
border: none;
border-radius: 50px;
padding: 5px 0px 5px 35px;
background: #fff url(images/google-logo.gif) no-repeat 10px center;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
}
`

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to adjust the layout of this widget using strictly CSS. The `<a>` elements containing links for all of the languages to choose from are laid out in `<td>` cells in rows. Therefore, they will not be laid out dynamically with resizing.

You can however, get around this by getting all the language links in the contained `<iframe>` and appending them to a `<div>` outside the `<table>`.

This should perform what you seek though may still require much CSS tweaking. Much of Google's UI elements are laid out manually with pixel dimensions and overridden attributes like `overflow:hidden` to avoid default (sometimes inconsistent) browser behavior. This solution may require a fair bit of [poking around the DOM][1] to determine where these adjustments are being done.

This should be executed in the top-most frame to access the `<iframe>` element and make changes to its CSS. Note that the selector is not a unique ID so it may return a different `<iframe>` than expected depending on the contents of your page.

```javascript
var iframe = document.querySelector('.goog-te-menu-frame.skiptranslate');

if (iframe === null) {

  console.error('Could not find iframe of language links');

} else {

// Force <iframe> visibility and auto-resizing
iframe.style.display = '';
iframe.style.height = '';
iframe.style.width = '99%!important';
```

This should be executed in the `about:blank` frame of the `<iframe>` to have access to the elements within.

```javascript
// Get all the <a> elements
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a.goog-te-menu2-item');
anchors = Array.prototype.slice.call(language_anchors);
if (anchors.length < 1) {
  console.error('Found no language links');
}

// Get the conatiner <div> that holds the table of links
var div = document.getElementById(':1.menuBody');

if (div === null) {

  console.error('Could not find div containing table of language links');

} else {

  // Remove width/height attributes to have <div> resize
  div.style.height = '';
  div.style.width = '';

  // Iterate through all language links
  anchors.forEach(function (a) {
      // Set display to inline=block so its rendered like text
      // This is what gets the elements onto a new line if they don't fit
      a.style.display = 'inline-block';

      // Append them directly to the <div>
      div.appendChild(a);
  });

  // Remove the now empty <table> to keep things clean
  div.removeChild(div.querySelector('table'));
}
```

This may break easily if Google changes their CSS class names or element IDs. Keep that in mind and happy rendering.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function googleTranslateElementInit() {
            new google.translate.TranslateElement({
                pageLanguage: 'en',
                layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.HORIZONTAL
            }, 'google_translate_element');
        }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>

</head>
    <body>

        <div id="google_translate_element"></div>

    </body>
</html>





YOU NEED TO CHANGE THE "SIMPLE" TO "HORIZONTAL"
```

Answer (score -2):

You can put this in your css file for the theme that you're using. Tweak it to make it work for you. Hope that helps!

```
select.goog-te-combo{width:100%!important;}
```